# JSONException on trying to create JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Please advice why I'm getting an exception on trying to create a JSONArray instance?

```
String task = "{'menu': { 'id': 'file', 'value': 'File', 'popup': { 'menuitem': [ {'value': 'New', 'onclick': 'CreateNewDoc()'}, {'value': 'Open', 'onclick': 'OpenDoc()'}, {'value': 'Close', 'onclick': 'CloseDoc()'}] }}}";
        try { 
            JSONObject tmp = new JSONObject(task);
            js = tmp.getJSONArray("menuitem"); // exception fires here
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting an exception

```
01-03 16:12:17.926: WARN/System.err(5999): org.json.JSONException: No value for menuitem
```

Comment: double check your string format

Comment: Actually you have no valid JSON. Strings and keys must be enclosed in double quotes `"`. But I don't know if this is enforced in Java's implementation.

Comment: No, single quotes are also fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'menuitem' is not a child of `tmp`. Try this:

```
js = tmp.getJSONObject("menu").getJSONObject("popup").getJSONArray("menuitem");
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:

JSON file:

```
{
    "response":
    {
        "results":
        [
            {
                "value1":"1",
                "value2":"2"
            },
            {
                "value1":"1",
                "value2":"2"
            }
        ],
        "status":
        {
            "code":"200",
            "message":"Success"
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
JSONArray array = responseObject.getJSONArray("results"); 
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
// CREATE YOUR OBJECTS
}
```